# Make ordered list scrollable

Tags: css

I have an order list that I would like to make scrollable.
[image]

I've tried just creating some `CSS` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.scrollable {
  height:150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I've attached this to the `OL`

UPDATED:
Below is the rendered HTML taking using show source on browser:

Should this work, or is it not as simple as that?

```
<div class="tab-content p-3 text-muted">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
        <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered scrollable">
            
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                <div class="fw-bold">Nov. 27, 2021, 2:57 p.m.</div>
                Another Event Again
                </div>
                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Go To Site</span>
            </li>
            
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                <div class="fw-bold">Dec. 1, 2021, 2:05 a.m.</div>
                the next event
                </div>
                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Go To Site</span>
            </li>
            
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                <div class="fw-bold">Dec. 12, 2021, 3:18 a.m.</div>
                And another event
                </div>
                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Go To Site</span>
            </li>
            
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                <div class="fw-bold">Dec. 15, 2021, 10:46 p.m.</div>
                Another Event
                </div>
                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Go To Site</span>
            </li>
            
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                <div class="fw-bold">Dec. 17, 2021, 10:46 p.m.</div>
                And Another Event
                </div>
                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Go To Site</span>
            </li>
            
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                <div class="fw-bold">Jan. 13, 2022, 10:46 p.m.</div>
                fsadfadsfafasf
                </div>
                <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Go To Site</span>
            </li>
            
            </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Apologies. Wasn't thinking. Rendered HTML added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it out and it seems to work for me. I can scroll at 150px.

A suggestion, make the div scrollable instead of the ol and check if it works.

```
div.tab-pane{ overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I'm not sure why. I'm using bootstrap so maybe this is blocking it

Comment: Make sure you have your custom css below the bootstrap css to override the setting